# Git Workflow in Build Artifacts inside a Cloned Repo

Tags: git, build, git-clone

I have 2 cloned repos and I am to build and generate executables (One single result file inside each repo) for each of them and push them onto a new repo. I encountered problem that the entire cloned repo + build artifact got pushed to the new repo. I only want the build artifacts in the new repo. Where in my git workflow is wrong?

git clone -> build -> git remote add new repo -> git add build artifact -> git commit -> git push new repo --force

Comment: Do you understand that Git doesn't push files — it pushes **chains** of commits?

Answer (score 1):

You're committing the built executables back to the original repo (the one where you got the source code). If you want a repo that's just the built executables, then you'll need to put those built executables in a separate repo.

(This is what you've asked for, but I think you'll do better to use an artifact or container registry, or even a cloud storage bucket, instead of Git for your binaries.)

Comment: Sorry, the git push at the end is actually git push new repo --force

Comment: But you're still committing in the original repo?

Comment: the orginal repo is fine, but the new repo got cloned original repo + build artifact

Comment: Yes - because you pushed the original repo plus artifacts to the new repo. If you want an artifacts-only repo, then you need to copy or move the artifacts to a separate local repo *before* committing.